# Optimal sequence for arbitrary sort order in a table

Tags: sql, algorithm, sorting, math

I'm sure there has to be a mathematical algorithm for this.

I'm creating a drag-and-drop UI for SQL tables which have an integer "sort order" field. The ones that, at present, users have to type a number into. It doesn't matter what the number actually is, just its relationship to the others in the sequence.

The problem, of course, is the spacing, collisions and rearrangement. Given a sequence of n items, if they were numbered sequentially, adding an item at position p would result in updating the values of n-p-1 elements.

I figure there has to be an algorithm out there for the most efficient spacing and re-balancing  (preferably piecemeal) of the numeric sequence.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have to use whole numbers? If you use some data type that allows you to use decimals, you can (almost always) find a new number to use between two existing ones just by taking their average.

Comment: Yes, I am writing this system to deal with existing databases which almost invariably use integers. The mid-point would be the position to use and, if they were floating values of infinite precision, that would be enough. I'm just trying to figure out what to do when it's not.

Comment: simulate it the same way you can simulate fixed point decimals using integers - start by multiplying all of the integers by (say) 10000. Then still use the midpoint method. Only when the gaps have closed up do you need to do a global renumbering to make them all multiples of 10000 again.

Comment: Whatever algorithm I use will have to start with the table in its existing state, even if that's sequential.
I know that if you adjust the preceding and next values before insertion (again, using the mid-point) then that will decrease the chances of a collision but at the cost of 2 extra writes and, I think, collisions would still be possible. This seems to be the sort of problem someone will have figured out an n-Log-n type calculation for.